# Multiple inner joins - Progress SQL ODBC

Tags: openedge, progress-db

How can I use multiple inner joins with the `select` statement in Progress ODBC SQL? I did lot of search and could not find anything.

The below SQL works, but only with 2 tables. I want to add 3 tables and don't know how to join.

```
SELECT so_mstr.so_nbr AS so_Number FROM PUB.so_mstr 
     INNER JOIN PUB.sod_det ON so_mstr.so_nbr = sod_det.sod_nbr 
                        AND so_mstr.so_domain = sod_det.sod_domain
```

Comment: What have you tried? What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1):

Found it. Maybe someone will find it useful.

```
SELECT `so_mstr`.`so_nbr` as `SO_Number` 
FROM (`PUB`.`so_mstr` INNER JOIN `PUB`.`sod_det` on `so_mstr`.`so_nbr` = `sod_det`.`sod_nbr` 
AND `so_mstr`.`so_domain` = `sod_det`.`sod_domain`) 
INNER JOIN  
`PUB`.`wo_mstr` ON (`so_mstr`.`so_nbr` = `wo_mstr`.`wo_so_job` AND `so_mstr`.`so_domain` = `wo_mstr`.`wo_domain`)
```